# Creating items from nested lists?

Tags: list, netlogo, nested-lists

I'm working on making my program interact with an overarching framework that transfers information with lists.

I have a breed called 'people' and I export information about them with

```
to srti-lists
 ask people [ foreach [self] of people [
  set traits-list (list (who) (color) (heading)(xcor)(ycor)(shape)]]
set master-list [traits-list] of people
end
```

It works great for exporting that information. What I'm having trouble with is creating or updating people with information that I then receive in the form of a master-list.

I've been approaching it as probably a foreach problem, but the problem is that while that lets me execute commands for every item of the master-list, I haven't figured out how to then access the individual nested items.

So, say:

```
foreach master-list
[create person 
set who item 0 master-list
```

etc. The problem is that syntax would create a person and then set the who as an entire sublist. Omitting the list throws up an error, and selecting the items more specifically is untenable since it'd be a list of variable length.

Any ideas how to iteratively select items from nested lists? Is foreach even the right approach?

Answer (score 2):

I can't test it but this looks wrong to me:

```
to srti-lists
 ask people [ foreach [self] of people [
  set traits-list (list (who) (color) (heading)(xcor)(ycor)(shape)]]
set master-list [traits-list] of people
end
```

`ask` already loops through the people, so this looks like it is assigning to each turtle the list of traits for all turtles, and then the master-list is a list of those lists. You probably want:

```
to srti-lists
 ask people [
  set traits-list (list (who) (color) (heading)(xcor)(ycor)(shape)]
set master-list [traits-list] of people
end
```

On the setting of traits, the `who` number cannot be set - it is assigned automatically when the turtle is created and can never be changed. For example, try the following complete (broken) model and you will get an error:

```
to testme
  create-turtles 5
  ask one-of turtles [set who 10 ]
end
```

So I don't know what you mean when you say that `who` is assigned an entire sublist - `who` is always an integer and assigned sequentially.

Concerning your stated question - your syntax `set who item 0 master-list` would be find if you were trying to `set` a variable that you could actually set.